# NSTimer won't fire with code optimization. Works fine without

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, timer, nstimer

I have some code that schedules a timer and then blocks the main thread kind of like this:

```
self.waitingForCompletion = YES;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
    NSTimer* timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:2.f target:self selector:@selector(finishCompletionWait:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
});

while(self.waitingForCompletion);

.
.
.

-(void)finishCompletionWait:(NSTimer*)timer {
    TFLog(@"Completion wait timer timed out");
    [timer invalidate];
    self.waitingForCompletion = NO;
}
```

When I run this with no optimization (-O0) the timer fires and the main thread unblocks. When I run this with fastest, smallest (-Os) the timer never fires and the main thread remains blocked forever. Is the problem here really the timer? Is it the threading? Is this the wrong way to block and unblock the main thread?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Why are you blocking the main thread? That's not something you normally want to do.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but the project I'm handed is so far gone, this is my only option. It clearly works without optimization, so let's just stick with the question at hand. Why I'm blocking the main thread is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

If a timer is created using this way, you should call 
[timer fire]